# find indices of 2 numbers in array that sums up to an number

Tags: haskell

I would like someone to review my code on find indices of 2 numbers in array that sums up to an number. Following is the code that I have tried and it works. 
The real issue in the code is I am doing Map.lookup twice. Is there a way to avoid it.

```
Input [1,2,3,4,5] 5
Output [2,1]

Input [1,2,3,4,5] 4
Output [2,0]
```

Code

````
import Data.Char
import Data.Maybe
import Data.List
import qualified Data.Map as Map
{--
 - two sums
 - https://leetcode.com/problems/two-sum/
 - --}
twosums :: [Int]-> Int -> [Int]
twosums [] _ = []
twosums k g = flip twosum' Map.empty $ zip k [0..]
  where
  twosum'::[(Int, Int)] -> Map.Map Int Int -> [Int]
  twosum' [] _ = []
  twosum' (x:xs) mp
    | Map.lookup (g - fst x) mp  == Nothing = twosum' xs qmap'
    | otherwise = [snd x, fromMaybe (-1) $ Map.lookup ( g - fst x)  mp ]
    where
    qmap' = Map.insert (fst x) (snd x) mp
```
````

Comment: The reason for off-topic is "Code not implemented or not working as intended". The code is working as intended. There are no bugs. I just want someone to help me on how I can avoid 2 lookup calls.

Comment: `twosum' ((n,i):xs) mp = case Map.lookup (g - n) mp of Nothing -> twosum' xs $ Map.insert n i mp; Just j -> [i, j]`

Comment: Thanks Gurkenglas, I found the answer on Haskell IRC beginner chat.